# C# ASP.NET MVC Запрет перехода по абсолютному пути к картинке

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Есть папка

> ~/GlobalFiles/PeoplePhoto/

Там фоточки.
Если я хочу получить фоточку, то пишу в адресную строку.

```
http://localhost:58370/GlobalFiles/PeoplePhoto/14.jpg
```

И получаю то, что хотел.

У каждого вошедшего есть роль, которая определяет на что пользователь имеет право, а на что нет. Так вот, получить фоточку можно любому по абсолютному пути, даже незарегистрированному. Как это исправить? Как проверять роль, перед переходом пользователя в данный каталог к конкретной фотографии.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Раздачу статического контента можно реализовать через контроллер, переложив на него все необходимые проверки прав доступа (через атрибуты контролера/метода или в самом теле функции).

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("GlobalFiles/PeoplePhoto/{photoId:int}")]
public ActionResult PeoplePhoto(int photoId)
{
    // Реализовать проверку прав доступа (в коде метода или через атрибуты)
    // Реализовать проверку на наличие файла отображения 
    byte[] imgBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath($"~/GlobalFiles/PeoplePhoto/{photoId}.jpg"));
    return File(imgBytes, "image/jpeg");
    //Если файла не существует —> return HttpNotFoundResult();
}
```

Для того, чтобы закрыть прямой доступ по ссылке к изображениям, в директории GlobalFiles разместите файл web.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments applyToWebDAV="true">
          <add segment="PeoplePhoto" />
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Альтернативным вариантом запрета доступа к изображениям может быть изменение логики сохранения файлов: например, сохранять файлы без явного указания их расширения, и/или сохранять файлы с именам в виде например, GUID'ов (с сохранением сопоставлений id <-> Guid в БД).

**Простой отказ от стандартного расширения (.jpg в вашем случае) вероятно, будет самым простым вариантом**: связано это с тем, что файлы jpg по-умолчанию обрабатывается `System.Web.StaticFileHandler'ом` и доступны напрямую по ссылке без какой-либо фильтрации. После удаления расширения (или изменения его на не обрабатываемое StaticFileHandler'ом — например «.hidden») доступ к файлу по прямой ссылке получить будет невозможно и без модификации web.config.

Ссылка на изображение будет иметь такой вид:

```
<img src="/GlobalFiles/PeoplePhoto/14" />
```

Comment: Здорово, работает!
Только вот по абсолютному пути я всё ещё могу обратиться...
Скрин: http://i.imgur.com/3LdujZk.png
Я не нашёл подходящей команды для блокировки просмотра по абсолютному пути.

И маленькая поправка при получении пути
System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Server.MapPath("....."));
Server.MapPath обязателен, без него путь кривой.

Comment: @Tima Дополнил ответ, обратите внимание на новый web.config. Для корректной работы должна быть установлена компонента IIS RequestFiltering. Так же рассмотрите альтернативный вариант с сохранением изображений под «непрямыми» названиями (и, особенно, расширениям).

Comment: Да, прочёл, работает идеально. Спасибо Вам большое!